# How to check against generic enum in Java?

Tags: java, generics, enums

Here is my code:

```
public enum DecisionType {

REFUSAL,
GRANT_OF_PROTECTION,
PARTIAL_REFUSAL;
}

public class DocumentComposition<T extends Enum<DecisionType>> extends TreeMap<DocumentType, Object> {

@Override
public Object put(DocumentType key, Object value) {
    if (key.getDecisionType() != ) {
        return null;
    }
    return value;
}
}

DocumentComposition map = new DocumentComposition<DecisionType.REFUSAL>();
```

I need my Map to contain only elements that are of a certain value of the DecisionType enum. How do I achieve this? What should my test look like?

Comment: Why don't you `extends TreeMap<DocumentType, T>`?

Comment: Why DO you extend TreeMap?  If you want your Map "to contain  only elements that are of a certain value of the DecisionType enum", just check their types with 'If' statement before putting on a map and decide whether you want to put it or not.

Comment: You could add a property to the enum as well but it's hard to now without understanding the logic behind the enum and the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand it right you want to have a DocumentComposition which accepts only DocumentType instances of a specific DecisionType ?
My parts of the solution:

- You don't need to use generics for that but rather an internal variable which you provide in the constructor.
- In you overridden put method you must not forget to call the super otherwise your TreeMap will never get any elements.

  ```
  public class DocumentComposition extends TreeMap<DocumentType, Object> {

      private DecisionType acceptedDecisionType;

      public DocumentComposition(DecisionType acceptedDecisionType)
      {
          this.acceptedDecisionType = acceptedDecisionType;
      }

      @Override
      public Object put(DocumentType key, Object value) {
          if (key.getDecisionType() != acceptedDecisionType) {
              return null;
          }
          return super.put(key, value); // do not forget to call super, otherwise your TreeMap is not filled
      }
  }
  ```

Now you can use your map:

```
    public static void main( String args[])
    {
        DocumentComposition dc=new DocumentComposition(DecisionType.REFUSAL);
        dc.put(new DocumentType(DecisionType.REFUSAL), "refusalDoc");
        dc.put(new DocumentType(DecisionType.PARTIAL_REFUSAL), "partialRefusalDoc");
        System.out.println(dc);
    }
```

Only refusalDoc will be in the map.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble of helping here. You're right of course, this is a simple way to handle this situation. I just thought, perhaps, there was an elegant way of doing it with generics... Somehow, from a design point of view, it was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure if generics can be used here as you want to specify an enum value and not a type as generic parameter.

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a confusion there. It's a pity though.